# Getting search results from youtube via bs4 python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get the first result from the youtube search query by scraping the page and open the page in the browser! This code does not work! And I am having problems finding the right class, id or selector to get the link.

I have tried to use  tags but some them return none.

```
import webbrowser
import urllib.request
import bs4 as bs

iarg = str(input('Query: '))

url = str('https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query={}'.format(arg))

req = urllib.request.Request(url, data=None, headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla'})
src = urllib.request.urlopen(req)

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(src, 'html.parser')

results = []

for elem in a = soup.find_all("a"):
    link = elem.get(href)
    results.append(link)

webbrowser.open(results[0])
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

Comment: What does not work - does it find the wrong results or no results at all? And what problem do you have finding the link? I'd say you need to list all tags there are and find the one you want. It takes a while to get this kind of thing sorted out.

Comment: Actually, I cannot find the best tag to get the link?